# MySQL count all NULL columns

Tags: mysql

I need to count and return the number of NULL columns in my MySQL query.

```
SELECT * from posttracks WHERE trackid=100000;
```

How would I `COUNT` all `NULL` columns?

Edit: to be clear, I don't need the number of rows that have null values, I need the number of columns in the row that have `NULL` values.

Comment: Do you mean NULL values in the column?

Answer (score 6):

If I understand your question correctly:

```
SELECT ISNULL(col1) + ISNULL(col2) + ... + ISNULL(col16) AS cnt
FROM yourTable
WHERE trackid=100000
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT count(*) from posttracks WHERE Col1 is NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are trying to find the all rows in which at least one column iS NULL.

Say, you have three columns - col1, col2, col3 in your table - table1.
then you can write the query as

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE col1 IS NULL OR col2 IS NULL OR col3 IS NULL.

If you are more columns, join them using OR

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*) as amount FROM posttracks WHERE trackid IS NULL GROUP BY trackid;
```

Answer (score 0):

`select count(*) from posttrack where trackid is null;`

Edit:
duplicate of previous answer